# Is it possible to improve this stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that though work fine but uses a lot of temp table and hence the performance degrades. Is it possible to improve/rewrite it (may be using CTE or something else manner for performance improvement)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PORT_GetFutureOpportunities] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (
        @SiebelAccId VARCHAR(50),
        @FromDate DATETIME,
        @ToDate DATETIME,
        @FilterCriteria INT,
        @AutoRenewalChk INT
    )
AS
BEGIN 

        DECLARE @FDate DATETIME, @TDate DATETIME 
        SET @FDate = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @FromDate), 0)
        SET @TDate = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @ToDate), 0)


        SELECT  DISTINCT e.nai_grant_number
        INTO #temp
        FROM smbecommerce..SalesItem si 
        INNER JOIN smbecommerce..sales s ON s.sales_id = si.sales_id
        INNER JOIN siebelextract..entitlement e ON SUBSTRING(e.nai_grant_number, 1,  NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', e.nai_grant_number) - 1, -1)) = CAST (s.sales_order_id AS VARCHAR)        
        WHERE  si.auto_renewal_flag = (CASE WHEN @AutoRenewalChk = 1 THEN 1 END )
        OR si.auto_renewal_flag <= ( CASE WHEN @AutoRenewalChk = 0 THEN 1 END)

            --Creating Main query
           SELECT 
           e.nai_agreement_account_name AS [CompanyName]
          ,c.first_name  + ' '  + c.last_name AS [ContactName]
          ,c.work_phone AS [ContactPhone]
          ,c.email_address AS [EmailAddress]
          ,e.entitlement_end_date AS [ExpirationDate]
          ,e.nai_grant_number AS [GrantNumber]
          ,e.nai_quantity AS [Quantity]
          ,e.product_name AS [SkuDescription]              
          ,(CASE WHEN LEN(e.nai_superceded_id) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [IsRenewed]

          INTO #temp1                  
          FROM siebelextract..entitlement e     
          INNER JOIN siebelextract..account a ON a.row_id = e.nai_reseller_id           
          INNER JOIN SiebelExtract.[dbo].contact c WITH (NOLOCK) ON e.nai_primary_contact_id = c.row_id 
          WHERE a.parent_account_id = @SiebelAccId
          AND LEN(E.nai_reason_code) = 0
          AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM smbecommerce..renewalskus rs WHERE RS.sku = E.product_name)
          AND e.entitlement_end_date 
          BETWEEN @FDate         
          AND @TDate   

          IF (@AutoRenewalChk = 0 OR @AutoRenewalChk = 1)
          BEGIN 
                  CREATE TABLE #temp2(
                                       CompanyName VARCHAR(200)
                                      ,ContactName VARCHAR(200)
                                      ,ContactPhone VARCHAR(200)
                                      ,EmailAddress VARCHAR(200)
                                      ,ExpirationDate DATETIME
                                      ,GrantNumber VARCHAR(200)
                                      ,Quantity INT
                                      ,SkuDescription VARCHAR(200)
                                      ,IsRenewed INT
                                     ) 
                 IF @AutoRenewalChk = 0
                 BEGIN  
                 INSERT INTO #temp2 select #temp1.* FROM #temp1       
                 END
                 IF @AutoRenewalChk = 1
                 BEGIN     
                 INSERT INTO #temp2 SELECT * FROM #temp1  WHERE #temp1.[GrantNumber] NOT IN(SELECT t1.nai_grant_number FROM #temp t1)     
                 END                       
                 END    

                IF @FilterCriteria = 0
                BEGIN 
                    SELECT te.[CompanyName],te.[ContactName],te.[EmailAddress],te.[ContactPhone],te.[SkuDescription],te.[Quantity],te.[GrantNumber],te.[ExpirationDate],te.[IsRenewed] FROM #temp2 te      
                END

                IF @FilterCriteria = 1
                BEGIN 
                    SELECT te.[CompanyName],te.[ContactName],te.[EmailAddress],te.[ContactPhone],te.[SkuDescription],te.[Quantity],te.[GrantNumber],te.[ExpirationDate],te.[IsRenewed]   FROM #temp2 te
                    WHERE te.[IsRenewed] > 0
                END         

                IF @FilterCriteria = 2
                BEGIN 
                  SELECT te.[CompanyName],te.[ContactName],te.[EmailAddress],te.[ContactPhone],te.[SkuDescription],te.[Quantity],te.[GrantNumber],te.[ExpirationDate],te.[IsRenewed] FROM #temp2 te
                  WHERE te.[IsRenewed] = 0
                END
                DROP TABLE #temp2
                DROP TABLE #temp1
                DROP TABLE #temp

END

GO
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe in words what this is supposed to do?

Comment: It could certainly exit sooner if `@AutoRenewalChk` isn't zero or one.  I would be inclined to restructure it so that it checked the `@AutoRenewalChk` and `@FilterCriteria` values using an `IF` tree and executed a single `SELECT` to do the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have compacted your stored procedure. Of course, I don't have your database so my SSMS looks like the battle of blood river, but based on the code you supplied, this should work. Have a look and please let me know, either way.

I'll paste the code first, and then explain what I've done.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PORT_GetFutureOpportunities (
    @SiebelAccId VARCHAR(50),
    @FromDate DATETIME,
    @ToDate DATETIME,
    @FilterCriteria INT,
    @AutoRenewalChk INT
)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @FDate DATETIME, @TDate DATETIME 
    SET @FDate = CAST(@FromDate AS DATE)
    SET @TDate = CAST(@ToDate AS DATE)

    CREATE TABLE #temp(
        CompanyName VARCHAR(200),
        ContactName VARCHAR(200),
        ContactPhone VARCHAR(200),
        EmailAddress VARCHAR(200),
        ExpirationDate DATETIME,
        GrantNumber VARCHAR(200),
        Quantity INT,
        SkuDescription VARCHAR(200),
        IsRenewed INT
    ) 

    WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT e.nai_grant_number    FROM smbecommerce..SalesItem si 
            INNER JOIN smbecommerce..sales s ON s.sales_id = si.sales_id
            INNER JOIN siebelextract..entitlement e ON SUBSTRING(e.nai_grant_number, 1,  NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', e.nai_grant_number) - 1, -1)) = CAST (s.sales_order_id AS VARCHAR)        
        WHERE  si.auto_renewal_flag = (CASE WHEN @AutoRenewalChk = 1 THEN 1 END)
            OR si.auto_renewal_flag <= (CASE WHEN @AutoRenewalChk = 0 THEN 1 END)),
        rs AS (SELECT DISTINCT sku FROM smbecommerce..renewalskus)
    INSERT INTO #temp
    SELECT e.nai_agreement_account_name, c.first_name  + ' '  + c.last_name, c.work_phone, c.email_address, e.entitlement_end_date,
        e.nai_grant_number, e.nai_quantity, e.product_name, (CASE WHEN LEN(e.nai_superceded_id) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM siebelextract..entitlement e     
        INNER JOIN siebelextract..account a ON a.row_id = e.nai_reseller_id           
        INNER JOIN SiebelExtract.dbo.contact c WITH (NOLOCK) ON e.nai_primary_contact_id = c.row_id 
        INNER JOIN rs ON rs.sku = e.product_name
        LEFT JOIN cte ON e.nai_grant_number = cte.nai_grant_number
    WHERE a.parent_account_id = @SiebelAccId
    AND LEN(E.nai_reason_code) = 0
    AND e.entitlement_end_date BETWEEN @FDate AND @TDate   
    AND (@AutoRenewalChk = 0 OR cte.nai_grant_number IS NOT NULL)

    SELECT CompanyName, ContactName, EmailAddress, ContactPhone, SkuDescription, Quantity, GrantNumber, ExpirationDate, IsRenewed 
    FROM #temp
    WHERE (@FilterCriteria = 0)
    OR IsRenewed = (1 - (@FilterCriteria -1))

    DROP TABLE #temp
END
```

1. Since you're using SQL2008, you have the benefit of being able to use the DATE type. Casting to DATE makes your intention a bit clearer than the DATEADD(DATEDIFF)) approach (which I liked - a novel way of stripping off the time).
2. Moved #Temp2 definition to the top and changed it to #Temp. This procedure doesn't need more than one temp table.
3. Changed original #Temp into a single-column CTE (named cte). There is also a sub-select that is going to cost you performance, from your sku table, so this was moved into a cte as well, named rs.
4. Changed  SELECT INTO #temp1 to insert into #Temp. The inner join to the rs common table expression filters the results in the same manner as before, but this will be much faster.
5. The entire `IF (@AutoRenewalChk = 0 OR @AutoRenewalChk = 1)` block has been replaced by two lines in the query: The left join with the cte, and the last line of the insert statement.
6. The @FilterCriteria check has been compacted and included in the final select statement. As per your code, if @FilterCriteria is 0, then all rows are returned. Otherwise, rows are returned where IsRenewed = 1 and @FilterCriteria = 1, or IsRenewed = 0 and @FilterCriteria = 2.

In fact, since all we're doing here is inserting data into the table and then selecting it, we can compact this even further into a single select statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PORT_GetFutureOpportunities (
    @SiebelAccId VARCHAR(50),
    @FromDate DATETIME,
    @ToDate DATETIME,
    @FilterCriteria INT,
    @AutoRenewalChk INT
)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @FDate DATETIME, @TDate DATETIME 
    SET @FDate = CAST(@FromDate AS DATE)
    SET @TDate = CAST(@ToDate AS DATE)

    WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT e.nai_grant_number    FROM smbecommerce..SalesItem si 
            INNER JOIN smbecommerce..sales s ON s.sales_id = si.sales_id
            INNER JOIN siebelextract..entitlement e ON SUBSTRING(e.nai_grant_number, 1,  NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', e.nai_grant_number) - 1, -1)) = CAST (s.sales_order_id AS VARCHAR)        
        WHERE  si.auto_renewal_flag = (CASE WHEN @AutoRenewalChk = 1 THEN 1 END)
            OR si.auto_renewal_flag <= (CASE WHEN @AutoRenewalChk = 0 THEN 1 END)),
        rs AS (SELECT DISTINCT sku FROM smbecommerce..renewalskus)
    SELECT e.nai_agreement_account_name AS [CompanyName], c.first_name  + ' '  + c.last_name AS [ContactName],
        c.work_phone AS [ContactPhone], c.email_address AS [EmailAddress], e.entitlement_end_date AS [ExpirationDate],
        e.nai_grant_number AS [GrantNumber], e.nai_quantity AS [Quantity], e.product_name AS [SkuDescription],
        (CASE WHEN LEN(e.nai_superceded_id) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [IsRenewed]
    FROM siebelextract..entitlement e     
        INNER JOIN siebelextract..account a ON a.row_id = e.nai_reseller_id           
        INNER JOIN SiebelExtract.dbo.contact c WITH (NOLOCK) ON e.nai_primary_contact_id = c.row_id 
        INNER JOIN rs ON rs.sku = e.product_name
        LEFT JOIN cte ON e.nai_grant_number = cte.nai_grant_number
    WHERE a.parent_account_id = @SiebelAccId
    AND LEN(E.nai_reason_code) = 0
    AND e.entitlement_end_date BETWEEN @FDate AND @TDate   
    AND (@AutoRenewalChk = 0 OR cte.nai_grant_number IS NOT NULL)
    AND ((@FilterCriteria = 0) OR CASE WHEN LEN(e.nai_superceded_id) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = (1 - (@FilterCriteria -1)))
END
```

Comment: Thanks Peter.. Yes I will admit that your sp doesnot give 100% result(it was obvious) but it certainly gave me some ideas by which i was able to solve mine in a pure set based approach. I will update my answer. But thanks anyways for guiding me

Answer (score 1):

- first of all ident the code. Its a mess to understand.
- too many temp tables. You load temp, load temp1, load temp2 with a
  copy of temp1 than load temp2 with a few more rows of temp1. You need
  to fid a way of joining these tables.
- also there is a big bug. If @AutoRenewalChk is 2 them temp 2 wont be
  created but will be access by a query. That will fail.
- finally, this may no improve performance but will generate a cleaner
  code, instead of having an IF for each possibility of
  @FilterCriteria, run the query and add a CASE on the where clause